# SQLDeveloper - seeing and modifying procedure code in another schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I see and modify procedure code in another schema? Right now I'm doing

```
select * from all_source
where name = 'MY_PROCEDURE'
```

But that's awful.

Comment: Why is that awful for viewing the code? To modify in another schema you'd need elevated privileges.

Comment: You want to ask how to find it in GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the simplest way is to show a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the connections panel expand you connection so you can see the list of object types (tables, views, etc.). Scroll to the bottom of that list and you'll see the last entry is 'Other Users'. Expand that and find the owner of the procedure in that new sub-list. Expand *that* and scroll down *their* object type list, expand the 'Procedures' list, and double-click the name of the procedure you're interested in.

That will let you see the source code. To modify it you will need your DBA to grant you the appropriate [privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#r126c1-t48), if they think it's a valid thing for you to be doing.

If you already have access to the schema you can just create a new connection using that, which would make this simpler.